# What is the ideal way to merge two Cassandra clusters with same keyspace into one?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

We have two clusters X and Y with same keyspaces but distinct data sets. We are planning to merge these into single cluster. What would be ideal steps to achieve this without downtime for applications? We have time series data stream continuously writing to Cassandra.

We have ruled out export/import as that will make us lose data during the time of copy.

We also ruled out sstableloader as that is not reliable. It fails often and there is not way to start from where it failed. Also it has same issue mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Do double writes (to both clusters) then any of the methods above will work.

1) A spark job is probably best if you have a ton of data.

2) import export is not as good as Brian's cassandra-loader so maybe give that a try https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader

> We also ruled out sstableloader as that is not reliable. It fails
>   often and there is not way to start from where it failed. Also it has
>   same issue mentioned above.

I'm assuming your writes are idempotent so it's not a huge deal if you need to run the job over.

Comment: Will the spark job keep the existing ttl and writetime information of each record in the new cluster? It doesn't look like. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: No but you could pull writetime for each record and specify a new ttl from spark if you wanted to. You can also specify an old writetime from spark.